# Adjusting the background color/picture for each workspace

Tags: 12.04, workspaces

I remember some years ago when playing with linux you could adjust the background color or picture independantly for each workspace, so you could have different colors on each space.

Is that possible in Ubuntu 12.04 lts ?

Comment: My apoligies ive now found the answer to this question using application "CCSM".

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called *wallpapoz* that will allow you to do many things with wallpapers including per workspace wallpaper.

```
sudo apt-get install wallpapoz
```

[source](http://www.linuxtoday.com/infrastructure/2009071900535MMGN)

for colors I have no idea.